# FancyBox 2: Set thumbnail helper source

Tags: jquery, fancybox, lightbox, fancybox-2

After reading several questions on stack, I realized that mine is a little different...

I have my fancy box elements nestes in several css styling divs. Because of my setup, the images that I want for my thumbnails aren't inside the anchors `<a><img/></a>` that FancyBox is set up to look at. Here there is the `→` text instead of an `<img>`. However, the images for each thumbnail that I want to use are close by. I am not exactly sure how I can customize the thumb helper source.

```
<div class="view">
   <div class="view-back">
      <span data-icon="A">111</span>
      <span data-icon="B">112</span>
      <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" rel="grp" title="ttl" href="page">→</a>
   </div>
   <img src="../..exampleImgSource"/>
</div>
```

The iframes will be grouped by the `rel` "grp" as it says here. Each element in the group with have the same nested `<div>` setup. What I want is to get each thumbnail to reference the `<img>` below.

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: and you have no way of changing `href="page"` to the image path?

Comment: I could, but I am not trying to link to an image. I am linking to another HTML page as an iFrame. Does my question make sense? The way this <div class="view"></div> works is that it takes my <img> below and has an curl effect on it. When a user hovers over it, it curls and shows a button that takes the user to the href HTML page. I want the nested "exampleImgSource" <img> as shown above